# Backbone.js Fetch without passing data as URL string

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Suppose I want to fetch data for a Backbone.js model, while passing additional data:

```
myModel.fetch{ data: { bar: true } };
```

If you look at your request in Firebug, Backbone appended this data on to the URL:

```
GET http://www.example.net/foo?bar=true
```

This data appears under the 'parameters' tab in Firebug.

However, if I call a `post` or `put` using Backbone, the extra data being posted is not sent in the URL, but appears under a 'PUT' tab in Firebug.

```
PUT http://www.example.net/foo //additional data is not included in URL
```

On my server side (i'm using Node.js > Express), I pull the passed params (example 1) with `request.query`, but I pull the passed data (example 2) with `request.body`.

#### My question:

Is it best practice to throw `get` params in the URL? Should I have my server-side simply look for `request.param` for all GETs, or, is there a way to have `Model.fetch()` pass 'data' instead of 'params'?

Comment: GET params can only go in the URL, there's nowhere else for them to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GET Method**

The GET operation, as defined in HTML, put the query string (or parameters) in the URL, and this is sent to the server. This is done because the GET should be used to retrieve data only. This data can be cached since you have the full parameters in the URL, this URL can be bookmarked and can stay in the browser history.

**POST Method**

A POST operation is intended to submit data to the server. No cache is done in this kind of operation. This is not stored in the browser history. Since you don't want to expose what you are sending the content goes in the body.

Saying this, the behaviour of the methods make sense and you should use this boths methods properly in your application and also take care of them in the server side independently.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I modified my server side to look for this.